# Is it possible that records are changed while a read query is still executing?

Tags: mysql, locking, concurrency, isolation-level, acid

Suppose a read (select) query R is reading some 100 records from a table, 50 records are read so far, could in the meanwhile a write query W change some of the unread records?

We didn't take any locks on the table (or to be read records).

I think it is obvious that reading single records (reading every record) is an atomic operation, but i am not sure about reading several (possibly millions) records. Is it an atomic operation? Do we need to take a read lock when reading multiple records (in one query) if it is possible that a write query be run in the meanwhile and we want a consistent snapshot of all of the records at the time the read query starts to be executed?

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and this may or may not be desirable. The database theory has a concept of [isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)), which is about transaction visibility to other processes. MySql's documentation about [`set transaction`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) has a discussion about product specific syntax.

Comment: just for sure, is reading a single record always an atomic operation?

Comment: InnoDB claims full ACID compliance, so no partial insert should be able to mess data consistency. That being said, with right isolation level, a transaction that won't be committed might mess up your data anyway. So, please study carefully the transaction isolation theory and documentation.